# What HTTP status code for a PUT to a data that cannot be modified?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

I need you to help me to decide what HTTP status code I should use.

I have data that I want to modify with a PUT request. This data have different states possible:
`draft`, `toConfirm`,`confirmed`,`refuse` etc.
I want to allow the modification only if the data's state is `draft` or `toConfirm`.

I would like to know which HTTP status code should I use if the date's state is neither `draft` or `toConfirm`? 400 for Bad Request ? 405 Method not allowed? 418?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [409 (Conflict)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) status code indicates that the request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target resource.

405 Method Not Allowed would also be *fine*.